# stored procedures location influence their performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, query-performance

I have a procedure SP_MYPRO that updates data in MYDB1.

1) the performance of SP_MYPRO would be different if I place it in MYDB2 instead of MYDB1?

2) what if the procedure SP_MYPRO only read data, does not update anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you can easily test for yourself, but in my testing, no, there is no significant overhead in calling a stored procedure across a database boundary (I am sure you could make something noticeable though if you tried hard enough).

However, I would say that a stored procedure should live closer to the data that it manipulates than the object(s) that call it. This way, if you move the database, all that breaks is the *remote* calls to that procedure, rather than all of them.

Comment: Apologies, I have done some tests and all worked fine, just I did not do anything extreme, like overloading CPU or I/O and make it difficult for the stored procedure to run.. that's why I posted it here, just in case someone tested a situation I could not foresee.

Comment: I have tested a stored procedure to generate reports from a replicated (subscription) database. I did not want to put the stored procedure in that database, in case they re-snapshot it from scratch.

Comment: Sure, there are exceptions to every rule. Without those details your responses are going to be for the general case.